# Intellij 2017 Gradle integration

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I am currently using Intellij IDEA 2017.1.5 for my projects. I have installed Gradle 3.3 (I was advised to use this version, since more recent ones would not work with the project I was working on).

However, whenever I try to import a build.gradle file, it doesn't allow it and give an error message - "Cannot import anything from [build.gradle path]". Furthermore, I am also unable to create a Gradle project, since that option does not appear on the side panel when I click -"Create New Project". However, I have options to create Groovy projects (I believe that is somehow related to Gradle).

I've also tried to install more recent versions of Gradle, without success. I know I've installed gradle correctly since I'm able to check its version using "gradle -v" on the cmd.

I am fairly recent to Gradle, and any help would be welcomed.

Comment: Any errors in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085)? Does the command line `gradle build` command work without errors in the project root directory?

Comment: There are no errors in the idea.log file. The gradle build command seems to work without errors. I'm starting to think this is a problem with Intellij itself, maybe.

Comment: Does it happen with any Gradle project you are trying to import?

Comment: I've tried 4 different Gradle projects, and none of them work. Due to my despair, I've seen a few tutorials on how to import Gradle projects, and in all of them, the build.gradle project has the little gradle icon. On my computer, the file has the empty file icon (not sure if this information is of any help to solve this).

Comment: Try the clean IntelliJ IDEA installation, delete the existing directories: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519.

Comment: Try intellij 2017.2?

Comment: @CrazyCoder thank you so much, it actually worked! Now I can both create and import Gradle projects! But just out of curiosity, why could this have happened? I've never dealt with Intellij's settings that much.

Comment: @tim_yates Well, I had also tried other versions and it didn't work. CrazyCoder's solution worked, but I'll install the new version shortly :)

Comment: It's impossible to tell what's the problem since you say that there was nothing related in the log.